# Help animating objects with different paths that merge

Tags: animation, splines

I need help animating 2 objects following 2 different paths, At some point i need them to ''merge'' together and continue.

[image: General image]

I did this  with two different splines and the constraint ''clamp to'' the animation is just cycle and at the end both objects follow the same route.

My problem is that at some point both object's speed change (the splines aren't exactly the same) and the objects start to grow near and overlap.

[image: Overlaping objects]

Is there a way to make this in a more efficent way so the objects don't overlap?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe just offset one of the objects that are on the curve so that there will be a gap when you merge

Comment: Yeah, I do that, but as time goes by they start to overlap!

Comment: Mitght be finnecky, but try 3 follow path constraints? 2 for the individual objects and the blend into the 3. one. Also: WIth follow path and the constraints you can keyframe the path's time, you can probably improve the timing that way.

Comment: Merging two arrays or object streams - The clip below would certainly remove the need to keep the arrays or object streams aligned, even loosely after they meet.  It's called masking and will post it as an answer if you want to go down that path. (no pun intended :)  )  It was done in vers 2.77 and I'm unsure if masking is still available in later versions, hence this comment first.  If it isn't you could fall back on Chroma Key (green screen) and mask that way.

The clip -

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2nf5wqhBpjeYAwd?e=SaUcDf